# subtracting time in R

Tags: r, excel

I've recently starting working in R to manipulate and query through excel files. I have an excel file called my_File.csv saved to my desktop. Here's what i have so far:

```
fileOpened <- sprintf("/Users/JimToby/Desktop/my_File.csv")

myFile <- as.data.frame(table(fileOpened[, c('user', 'time', 'event')]))
```

myFile leaves me with a table looking like this:

user | time |

use1 |2011-07-25 13:08 |

use1 |2011-08-06 2:37 |

use2 |2011-07-25 13:08 |

.....

What I want to do is add another column that has the difference in time per each user. For instance the column could be called timeDiff and for use1 would have only one result by doing 2011-08-06 2:37 - 2011-07-25 13:08. How would i compute this and incorporate it into my table?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't add the rstudio tag unless you have a specific question about rstudio. R and rstudio are independent pieces of software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you convert the data to an actual time format, you can just subtract. Your sample data only had a start for user2 so I added an end time so that there is a real example. I assumed that you have the times as strings and that you wanted to store the time difference back in the same data.frame

```
myFile = read.table(text='user  time
use1 "2011-07-25 13:08" 
use1 "2011-08-06 2:37" 
use2 "2011-07-25 13:08"
use2 "2011-08-04 3:45"',
header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

T2 = as.POSIXct(myFile$time)
EndTime = seq(2,length(T2),2)
myFile$timeDiff[EndTime] = T2[EndTime] - T2[EndTime-1]
myFile
  user             time  timeDiff
1 use1 2011-07-25 13:08        NA
2 use1  2011-08-06 2:37 11.561806
3 use2 2011-07-25 13:08        NA
4 use2  2011-08-04 3:45  9.609028
```

Note that the resulting time differences are in days.

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution with `shift` in `data.table`:

```
dt <- read.table(text = "user | time
           use1 |2011-07-25 13:08
           use1 |2011-08-06 2:37
           use2 |2011-07-25 13:08", header = T, sep = "|")
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(dt)
dt[, time := as.POSIXct(time)]
dt[, time.diff := time - shift(time, type = "lag"), by = user]
#               user                time     time.diff
# 1:            use1  2011-07-25 13:08:00       NA secs
# 2:            use1  2011-08-06 02:37:00 11.56181 secs
# 3:            use2  2011-07-25 13:08:00       NA secs
```